# jquery datatables - trigger export function via href

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

can someone explain how I can trigger the export function (copy, csv, ...) by clicking an href link. Is this possible? Below code creates the buttons but how can I assign the action to my li-elements?

Example Code:

HTML:

```
 <ul class="menulist">
<li><a href="#">Copy</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Text File (*.txt)</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Excel File (*.xlsx)</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#example').DataTable(
      {"pagingType": "full_numbers",
         "bStateSave": true,
            "sDom": "<'row'<'col-xs-6 col-left'l><'col-xs-6 col-right'<'export-data'T>f>r>t<'row'<'col-xs-6 col-left'i><'col-xs-6 col-right'p>>",
dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                        "oTableTools": {
              "sSwfPath" :"???",
            "aButtons": [
            {'sExtends': "copy", "mColumns": "visible",  "bFooter": false,  "bSelectedOnly": true},
            {'sExtends':'csv',"sFileName": "test.csv"},
            {'sExtends':'xls',"sFileName": "test.xls",}
            ]       
        },

      }
    );
});
```

Here's a [Link](http://live.datatables.net/yisibuw/2/edit?js,output) I test with.

**UPDATE:**
just to point out: I'm already using dataTools which works fine with the standard buttons that are created but I need to customize it so that I can use it in other elements/objects.

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at TableTools: [https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/](https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/)

Comment: I'm already using that - instead of the standard buttons I want to have those links in hrefs.

Comment: I know it's not quite what you're looking for, but the buttons _are_ links with css styles applied.  You could strip off the styles from the `DTTT_button DTTT_button_copy` class and you'd be left with a text link.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `sSwfPath` path :

```
"sSwfPath" :"???",
```

Replace that with url to your swf file. Becouse export is done by flash.

Example from [tabletools doc](http://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/initialisation) :

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        }
    } );
} );
```